# disabling menu for an amount of time android

Tags: android, menu

my question is this:

Can I disable menu button for a certain amount of time? I mean setting from ym app that for the next 10 minutes for example, if I press menu nothing will happen, even if I am in other app. After that time is pressed, menu functionalith will be retrieved.

My app will run in the backgrounf of course and will check the time, but I do not know if it is possible to "disable" that button. I am not asking on how to implement the time, but on how to disable the menu button.

Comment: Every application handles menu button on its own, so I doubt it's possible.

Comment: Surely, what you are trying will not provide seamless user experience and you will also get lots of negative votes on the app store. Tell us why you want such a wierd looking thing in your app and we might tell you a better solution.

Comment: Well it not for market. A friend of mine told me to do for its personal use, because in a certain game he accidentaly some times presses menu button and as a result of this he quits the game. So he wants that app in order to remove that functionality for les say one hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does it work?

The menu-event is handled inside the Android Framework. The framework *consumes* the KEYCODE_MENU. With other words, the event will not be dispatched and will never arrive in your application layer. This means, you can **not** override this functionality.

When you are building a new platform, you can alter the framework yourself. Inside the [PhoneWindowManager](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java) (where the default `KeyEvents` are being handled like `KEYCODE_HOME`) you can add logic to handle the `KEYCODE_MENU` inside the method `interceptKeyBeforeDispatching(..)`.

Comment: In Android, as in an stand alone application.. Not possible. :)